# Custom NUnit Constraint in VB.net - Cannot Override ApplyTo

Tags: vb.net, nunit, nunit-3.0

I'm trying to write a custom contrain for nunit (3) in vb.net  Simplest example (following the docs) would be:

```
Namespace MYConstraints
    Public Class MyConstraint
        Inherits NUnit.Framework.Constraints.Constraint

        Public Overrides Function ApplyTo(Of TActual)(actual As TActual) As NUnit.Framework.Constraints.ConstraintResult
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Function
    End Class

End Namespace
```

(The `ApplyTo` definition was added by Visual Studio automatically even, when I inherited the nunit `Constraint` class)

Problem is, it won't compile!

I get two errors:

> BC30518   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'That' can be
>   called with these arguments:
>
> 'Public Shared Overloads Sub That(Of TActual)(del As ActualValueDelegate(Of TActual), expr As IResolveConstraint)': 
>   Type parameter 'TActual' cannot be inferred.
>
> 'Public Shared Overloads Sub That(Of TActual)(actual As TActual, expression As IResolveConstraint)': 
>   Type parameter 'TActual' cannot be
>   inferred.

And

> BC30935   Member 'Public MustOverride Overloads Function ApplyTo(Of
>   TActual)(actual As TActual) As ConstraintResult' that matches this
>   signature cannot be overridden because the class 'Constraint' contains
>   multiple members with this same name and signature:
>
> 'Public MustOverride Overloads Function ApplyTo(Of TActual)(actual As
>   TActual) As ConstraintResult'
>       'Public Overridable Overloads Function ApplyTo(Of TActual)(ByRef actual As TActual) As ConstraintResult'

Looking at the [nunit source](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/master/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Constraints/Constraint.cs) for the `Constain class` I see that they have defined two variants with the same signature:

```
/// <summary>
/// Applies the constraint to an actual value, returning a ConstraintResult.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="actual">The value to be tested</param>
/// <returns>A ConstraintResult</returns>
public abstract ConstraintResult ApplyTo<TActual>(TActual actual);

/// <summary>
/// Applies the constraint to an ActualValueDelegate that returns
/// the value to be tested. The default implementation simply evaluates
/// the delegate but derived classes may override it to provide for
/// delayed processing.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="del">An ActualValueDelegate</param>
/// <returns>A ConstraintResult</returns>
public virtual ConstraintResult ApplyTo<TActual>(ActualValueDelegate<TActual> del)
{
#if ASYNC
    if (AsyncInvocationRegion.IsAsyncOperation(del))
        using (var region = AsyncInvocationRegion.Create(del))
            return ApplyTo(region.WaitForPendingOperationsToComplete(del()));
#endif
    return ApplyTo(GetTestObject(del));
}
```

One is abstract with a pass-by-value parameter and the other is virtual with a reference param, but that's surely not enough to distinguish them when calling?

The tooltip error in Visual Studio (VS 2015 Professional if it makes a difference) is:
[image]
So it looks like it's interpreting the `ActualValueDelegate<TActual>` as a `ByRef TActual` in vb.net

So, two questions:

1. How is this possible?  (Is this allowed in C# but not vb.net?  or
   have I misunderstood something?) - this is just that I am curious :)
2. How should I write a custom constrain in vb.net?  (Does anyone have
   an example?)  This is my main question :)

I'm increasingly convinced this is a bug - something valid in C# that doesn't translate to vb.net maybe.  Have created a bug at https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/2263

Comment: You haven't given the code that is failing to compile - that is the code that uses Assert.That with this constraint. Please add that to get more help.

Comment: The two overloads you list do not have the same signature. One takes a first arg of type TActual while the other takes ActualValueDelegate of TActual. There is no TActual ByRef. Did you list the overloads you intended to show?

Comment: Hi Charlie, I'm running into the same VB compile errors. re: The two overloads you list do not have the same signature. VB compiler is displaying that error message indicating it thinks the two overloads are the same. re: There is no TActual ByRef.: The VB compiler is displaying that the ApplyTo signature takes "By Ref Actual As TActual".  I've tried every combination of overrides, shadows, overloads, etc. that I can think of. I can't get this to complete.

Comment: Hi Charlie, Also, as the OP mentioned I let VB compiler generate the method snippets. The VB doesn't like the generated snippets. I was able to create a function:     Public Overrides Function ApplyTo(Of TActual)(Actual As ActualValueDelegate(Of TActual)) As Constraints.ConstraintResult. I'm guessing the problem is that the NUnit C# code is not translating to VB method signatures as one would expect. To solve this problem I've had to downgrade to an earlier version of Nunit.

Comment: Did some investigation. 1) I downgraded NUnit to each version from 3.7 to 2.6.3. I got the same errors. 2) I have two projects subclassing Nunit Constraint class. Project 1 custom constraint compiles successfully, but can't see Constraint metadata when I click on Go to Definfition;  project 2 I get errors as listed by OP, I can see Constraint Meta Data. I compared syntax between both custom constraints and made sure they are the same. Both projects are: VS 2017 Community Edition, .Net 4, VB.

Comment: @Charlie: It is the constraint itself that won't compile.  I.e. the Test project fails to compile.  So i have listed the code that fails :)  Will add about the byRef

Comment: OK... I saw one error message that mentions `That`, which confused me.

Comment: @Charlie, Yesterday, I played around with trying to get a VB version to work for some time. The only solution I could get to work was to create a C# project in my VB solution and convert my VB custom constraint to C#.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be confirmed as a bug in nunit.  See https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/2263

Comment: I was torn between a bug and a feature. Some folks would say "Can't be used from VB" isn't a problem. :-) If you read the issue, it's a non-trivial fix requiring a change in the interface. The method that takes a ref might need to get a new name, putting a burden on the caller to know what method is appropriate.